# Does REMOVE ever return the same sequence, in practice?

Tags: common-lisp

Does [REMOVE](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/fun_removecm__elete-if-not.html) ever return the same sequence in any real implementations of Common Lisp?  The spec suggests that it is allowed:

> The result of remove may share with
>   sequence; the result may be identical
>   to the input sequence if no elements
>   need to be removed.

SBCL does not seem to do this, for example, but I only did a crude (and possibly insufficient) test, and I'm wondering what other implementations do.

```
CL-USER> (defparameter *str* "bbb")
*STR*
CL-USER> *str*
"bbb"
CL-USER> (defparameter *str2* (remove #\a *str*))
*STR2*
CL-USER> (eq *str* *str2*)
NIL
CL-USER> *str* 
"bbb"
CL-USER> *str2*
"bbb"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Returning the original string could be useful. In case no element of a string gets removed, returning the original sequence prevents allocation of a new sequence. Even if a new sequence has been allocated internally, this new sequence could be turned into garbage as soon as possible.

CLISP for example returns the original string.

```
[1]> (let ((a "abc")) (eq a (remove #\d a)))

T
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it mostly depends on the implementation. On the whole, I suspect it's not that common, as the typical case would be that something gets removed when REMOVE is called, so making a space optimisation for the nothing-removed case would incur a run-time penalty and not necessarily saving any space, since you'd want to allocate space for the return value for strings and arrays and would either need to construct a list as you go OR do a two-pass operation.